# scripted camera movement in cinema 4d to unity3d?

Tags: unity-game-engine, camera, cinema-4d

I have a scene in cinema 4d, with a camera that moves through the scene. I was hoping that I could just import the entire cinema4d file into unity3d and I could just magically press play, and the scene would just.. work--camera movement and all.

Well, maybe life is not that easy. Is it even possible to import a camera from cinema into unity?

It would be nice not to have to re-program the camera in unity.

Do I have any options?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is no, there is no "concept of" a camera path you can import to Unity. There is nothing whatsoever like that. (Don't forget, it's a game engine - not an animation or "filmmaking" system really.)

Fortunately this is a relatively common problem.

The solution is just that you put "any old thing" (say, a white cube) there and import that animation.  Then in Unity it's trivial to just child the camera to that "marker".

You can google many examples,

http://answers.unity3d.com/answers/20413/view.html

try googling say "import camera move to Unity3d"

---

BTW I'm sure you're aware of this .. *"Unity does not import Point Level Animations (PLA) at the moment. Use Bone-based animations instead."* [Doco](http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/HOWTO-ImportObjectCinema4D.html)

Comment: Nice! Thanks for the info!

Comment: Okay. Whatever Joe Blows goes.

Answer (score 0):

Another more hackish workaround;

I have once made a scene in Cinema4D which I wanted to use in Unity3d. I ended up employing MOCCA to export the camera's positions and rotation-values on it's keyframes and ended up using coding on the Unity end of things to animate the camera, based on an xml-file.

However, not having used Cinema4D in a bit; I can't remember for sure if MOCCA is still available? If memory serves me right it got replaced with something...